# hardhat fork of private network with zero gas fees still requires a balance to perform a transaction

Tags: private-blockchain, hardhat, forks, blockchain-fork

I forked my private network in hardhat using the below hardhat.config.js
My network gas zero gas fees so we dont have any balances.

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
      forking: {
        url: 'http://X.X.X.X:8545',
        blockNumber: 8547373
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When i try and perform a transaction against a contract i get this error:

> InvalidInputError: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The
> max upfront cost is: 29024280000000000 and the sender's account only
> has: 0

I have set the base fee to zero using `setNextBlockBaseFeePerGas(0);` but it still requires some gas.

How can i set the gas fee to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set the gas fee to zero on your forked private network in Hardhat, you can use the "gasPrice" option in your network configuration. You can set the gas price to 0 in the hardhat network configuration file.

Set a default gas price for all transactions by extending the Hardhat network provider in your hardhat.config.js file.

Run:

```
npm install --save-dev @ethersproject/providers
```

Modify hardhat.config.js

```
const { privateKey } = require('./secrets.json'); // import or create your private key
const { extendConfig, extendEnvironment } = require('hardhat/config');
const { HardhatEthersProvider } = require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/providers');
const { JsonRpcProvider } = require('@ethersproject/providers');

extendConfig((config, userConfig) => {
  config.networks.hardhat.accounts = [
    {
      privateKey,
      balance: '10000000000000000000000', // Optional: set an initial balance for this account
    },
  ];
});

extendEnvironment((hre) => {
  class ZeroGasPriceProvider extends HardhatEthersProvider {
    async send(method, params) {
      if (method === 'eth_sendTransaction') {
        params[0].gasPrice = params[0].gasPrice || '0x0';
      }
      return super.send(method, params);
    }
  }

  hre.network.provider = new ZeroGasPriceProvider(
    new JsonRpcProvider(hre.network.config.url),
    hre.network.config
  );
});

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
      forking: {
        url: 'http://X.X.X.X:8545',
        blockNumber: 8547373,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

This custom provider, ZeroGasPriceProvider, extends the default HardhatEthersProvider and sets the gas price to zero for all transactions if it's not already set. With this setup, you don't need to specify the gas price for each call:

Comment: I did this, but i still need to specify the gasPrice in my calls. Is there any way i can default the gas price to zero without having to specify it?
await myContract.connect(ownerWallet).myFunction(1,2,3, {gasPrice: 0});

Comment: Updated answer for you